# Append a value at the end of the list, only if does not exist. in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I do have 200 voluteers  receiving a gift from a donation, 
All of them have volunteer cards
What I want to achieve is a simple duplication control system
A volunteer come in , we type or scan his Badge, 
The easiest thing is to check if the value exists 
So lets say IN Column A1 I add the number Column B1

```
  A      B
VAlue Result
```

and column A in Sheet 2 has all the numbers

So its easy with a function like this to check if the number exists

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!:$A$2:$A$1000,0),"Yes"),"No")
```

If the number does not exist I want to Append in Sheet 2 in column A

How I should do it

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Couldn't you append the number manually as the applicant claims his gift and use the formula you have to tell you on the spot that it isn't his first claim - if so?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provided some images, I understand that maybe this is what you want.let' putting this code into Sheet1 code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Sheet2_ColumnA As Range: Set Sheet2_ColumnA = Sheets("sheet2").[a1:a10000]
    If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "A2" Or Not (IsError(Application.Match([a2], Sheet2_ColumnA, 0))) Then Exit Sub
    Sheet2_ColumnA.Cells(10000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = [a2] 'set lastcell in sheet2-columnA value
End Sub
```